# Can't Lazy Load Firebase v9's "useAuthState" & "auth" in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, lazy-loading

I have a React app that I'm trying to optimise. It's easy enough to Lazy Load components, but where I've found myself stuck is trying to asynchronously load and code-split the firebase dependencies.

They take up 80% of the initial loading js, and I don't need them to do anything until the page loads anyway, but they are bundled with the `main.chunk.js`.

I've tried to Lazy import:

```
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { auth } from "./firebase";


function App() {
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

    ...
```

But you're not allowed to import Non-ReactComponent functions.

So I tried to load the useAuthState() in `useEffect`, but i'm not allowed to `set hooks to a hook`, which kind of makes sense.

This is the error I get:
`React Hook "useAuthState" cannot be called inside a callback.`

How can I Lazy Load the firebase components till after the page is initially loaded?

This is what the `main.js` is compiled with:

```
…js/main.bbdadee4.js(herospace.app)
../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js
../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js
../node_modules/@firebase/firestore-compat/src/api/database.ts
../node_modules/@firebase/auth/src/core/auth/auth_impl.ts
../node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/node_modules/google-closure-library/closure/goog/labs/net/webchannel/webchannelbase.js
```

But

```
../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js
```

is the only one I need to load the initial state of the page, which is why i'm trying to delay any firebase scripts from being loaded.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around, that doesn't bundle the firebase packages, or lazy load them, but instead I just extended a route for the authorized part of the app.

Instead of `example.com/a-blog-post` being on the same route as `example.com/editProfile` *(a route that needs Firebase)*, I've moved everything to `example.com/app/editProfile`

I then only load Firebase imports in `/app`, and Lazy Load the component that renders when `/app` is reached.

I would still enjoy a lazy load option for firebase, but until then, this solution will do fine. Both mobile & desktop PageSpeed scores are green & 95+/100, so I'm satisfied.

I'm not marking this as the answer, because I still think there's a more proper & valid answer.